# /var/log/auth.log in Ubuntu under WSL

Tags: login, users, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Where do I find login information when running Ubuntu under Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?  I would normally expect it to be in `/var/log/auth.log`, but I don't see any login attempts there.

Output of my `/var/log/auth.log`:

[image: Output of my /var/log/auth.log]

Comment: Have you actually *tried* checking that path?  Because that's where it normally is on Ubuntu.  Might be different with WSL at play though

Comment: @ThomasWard i tried command  sudo less /var/log/auth.log and  it didn't give me exactly what I expected to see.Now I will update the question and add a screenshot.

Comment: which proves this is an XY question, because you're asking specifically about a potential 'solution' for getting unspecified information.  What is your *actual* issue you're trying to solve/figure out?

Comment: @ThomasWard I just need follow the file where logins are logged

Comment: define "logins" - is this a VM?  Or WSL?  Straight WSL when executed via the 'bash' function and Ubuntu app in Windows doesn't store a login log.  (Just checked on my WSL2 system).  If this is WSL then auth.log might not help you, logins likely are at the Windows level (WSL wasn't designed to run independently of a user login on Windows necessarily).  So unless you're running an SSH server inside of WSL, and SSHing into the WSL environment, there won't be 'typical' login logs.

Comment: @ThomasWard yep ,WSL.Do I understand correctly that information about the user name that I entered for the first time when I installed ubuntu is not saved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129331/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-y-sgard).

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons you don't see a `/var/log/auth.log` under WSL:

- First, WSL doesn't run any services by default, including `rsyslog`.  Without a system logging service, well ... no syslogs!  I'm assuming you already have figured this part out since you *do* have a `/var/log/auth.log`, though.  For others that are reading this, you would need to do a `sudo service rsyslog start` to start the logging service.
- Second, as ThomasWard pointed out in the comments and discussion, WSL does not "login" in a traditional sense.  Specifically, under Ubuntu, PAM (pluggable authentication modules) is used to authenticate users.  And PAM is what logs the authentication information to syslog, typically resulting in the output you expect in `/var/log/auth.log`.

  But you'll notice that you don't enter a password when starting WSL.  This is because WSL's `/init` process (its PID 1 which is the parent of all other processes) starts your shell as the [default user](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).  Passwords aren't that useful in WSL, since it's your *Windows* user that ultimately determines your access rights to the system.  Put another way, even `root` in WSL can never exceed the permissions of the Windows user.

  Since you're already logged in to Windows, WSL doesn't need the "extra protection" of a WSL user password.

However, as you've seen in your existing `/var/log/auth.log`, there *are* things that you can do to trigger PAM, and thus trigger writes to the log.  The two most common are `su` and `sudo`.

Also note that the `/etc/securetty` message that you are seeing in the log is due to the [pam_securetty](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_securetty) module attempting to look for its configuration.  Since that's not configured (or needed) under WSL, Ubuntu does not provide that file by default.